# wordpress home page working but inner pages not working on windows server

Tags: wordpress, iis

wordpress home is working on IIS Server but inner pages not working and  i am getting error message "No input file specified."

WP admin is working very well .

SITE URL : http://dat.co.uk/demo/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct redirect rules for permalinks? it's not the same as on an apache server. see here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress